# Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 root knox?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab-4, samsung-knox

I see directions for carrier based versions of the galaxy tablet, but none seem to mention the particular one that I have(a wifi only sm-t230nu). they also mention Knox, but I cannot tell if it is installed by default on this model. if I root/flash this type of tablet, will it trigger this Knox and render it serviceable or is that a feature specific to certain types of tablets?

Answer (score 0):

According to Samsung's website, the Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 comes with Knox.  Are you asking if the Knox enterprise features will be enable (where it creates a "safe" environment on your table) or if it will trip the Knox flags, essentially telling Samsung service departments that you've tinkered with it and voided your warranty?

Comment: I do not use this in an enterprise environment, so I probably won't need enterprise features unless there is a good reason for them

Comment: I think your bigger concern then is that it will probably trip the Knox flag, telling samsung that the device is not stock and has been "tampered with". It makes a good excuse for them not to have to deal with any warranty issues, whether they are related to what rooting does or not.

Comment: basically,yes. I'm not sure what does and doesn't count specifically for voiding, and would rather not accidentally set a flag I didn't know about

Comment: This may be more information than you want, but here are all of the gory details on the mysterious Knox flag: http://omegadroid.co/wanted-knox-void-warranty-0x1/